# Como incluir valores na mesma section, sem sobrescrever a anterior?

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

Eu tenho uma `view` que inclui outra `view` . Quero que essas mesmas views incluam um javascript na section da `view` principal chamada `javascripts`.

Assim:

```
#layout.blade.php

<head>@yield('javascripts')</head>
<div id="container">@yield('container')</div>
```

Na minha `view` onde eu uso para cadastrar os usuário tenho o seguinte:

```
#usuario/cadastra.blade.php
@extends('layout')
@section('container')

<form>
@include('usuarios._form', ['botao' => 'Cadastrar');
</form>

@stop

@section('javascripts')
{{ HTML::script('js/usuarios/cadastra.js') }}
@stop
```

Essa é outra view, que é usada no include, que é `usuarios._form`.

#usuarios._form.blade.php

```
<!-- Meu formulário aqui -->

@section('javascripts')
{{ HTML::script('js/usuarios/_form.js') }}
@stop
```

Eu preciso que os dois javascript incluídos nas `@section('javascripts')` apareçam juntos, porém só aparece o último, que é o da view `usuarios/cadastra.blade`.

Como posso fazer para os dois aparecerem juntos?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No Laravel 5.2 temos o [`@stack`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/blade#stacks) para fazer isso, alterando poucas coisas:

```
#layout.blade.php

<head>@stack('javascripts')</head>
<div id="container">@yield('container')</div>
```

```
#usuario/cadastra.blade.php
@extends('layout')
@section('container')

<form>
@include('usuarios._form', ['botao' => 'Cadastrar');
</form>

@stop

@push('javascripts')
  {{ HTML::script('js/usuarios/cadastra.js') }}
@endpush
```

```
#usuarios._form.blade.php

<!-- Meu formulário aqui -->

@push('javascripts')
  {{ HTML::script('js/usuarios/_form.js') }}
@endpush
```

No seu caso dá pra fazer também com `@parent`

```
#layout.blade.php

<head>@yield('javascripts')</head>
<div id="container">@yield('container')</div>
```

```
#usuario/cadastra.blade.php
@extends('layout')
@section('container')

<form>
@include('usuarios._form', ['botao' => 'Cadastrar');
</form>

@stop

@section('javascripts')
  {{ HTML::script('js/usuarios/cadastra.js') }}
@endsection
```

```
#usuarios._form.blade.php

<!-- Meu formulário aqui -->

@section('javascripts')
  @parent
  {{ HTML::script('js/usuarios/_form.js') }}
@endsection
```

Comment: Hehe, legal... Dessa aí eu não sabia.

Answer (score 1):

De maneira simples e direta, basta você parar de usar o `@stop` no final das suas declarações e passar a usar `@append`.

Apesar  de não ter visto nada na documentação a respeito, a classe `BladeCompiler` possui alguns método que são precedidos por pela palavra 
"compile" antes, cuja funcionalidade é compilar aquile é capturado depois do `@`.

Ou seja, lá existe o método `compileAppend`. Sendo assim, você pode fazer da seguinte forma em suas views:

```
@section('javascripts')
{{ HTML::script('js/jquery.js') }}
@append


@section('javascripts')
{{ HTML::script('js/undescore.js') }}
@append
```

No final tudo é compilado para o `@yield('javascripts')`.

Nesse caso, quando for fazer coisas do tipo, recomendo sempre que use `@append` ao invés de `@stop`, exceto para o caso do `@section('content')`.